Using for loop reading with multiprocessing missing iterables
Sorry if I'm wording this wrong, below is my script, I'm trying to figure out why when I review the archive file (that I created) I only see 9874 lines when the file to open/read has 10000. I guess I'm trying to uderstand why some iterations are missing. I've tried it a few times and that number always varies. What am I doing wrong?
import multiprocessing
import hashlib
from tqdm import tqdm

archive = open('color_archive.txt', 'w')

def generate_hash(yellow: str) -> str:
    b256 = hashlib.sha256(yellow.encode()).hexdigest()
    x = ' '.join([yellow, b256])
    archive.write(f"{x}\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    listofcolors = []   
    with open('x.txt') as f:
        for yellow in tqdm(f, desc="Generating..."):
            listofcolors.append(yellow.strip())
           
    cpustotal = cpu_count() - 1
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(cpustotal)
    results = pool.imap(generate_hash, listofcolors)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
print('DONE')

This script executes fine however  when looking at the archive file some lines are missing for example a file with 10000 lines only wrote 9985 lines to the new file, what am I doing wrong?

You're trying to share a single open file handle between a number of different processes.  There is no interlocking, and the buffers are not shared, so the writes will sometimes collide with each other.  The right way to do this is to send the data back to the original process using a Queue, and have the main process be the only writer to the file.

Here's another way to think about the problem.  Each process does its work and returns the value to the main process, which writes to the file.  This is like doing a "Queue" without explicitly using a queue.
import multiprocessing
import hashlib
from tqdm import tqdm

def generate_hash(yellow: str) -> str:
    b256 = hashlib.sha256(yellow.encode()).hexdigest()
    return yellow + " " + b256 + "\n"    

def main():
    archive = open('color_archive.txt', 'w')
    with open('x.txt') as f:
        listofcolors = [s.strip() for s in f]
           
    cpustotal = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(cpustotal)
    for s in pool.imap(generate_hash, listofcolors):
        archive.write(s)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    print('DONE')


thank you so much!!! for explaining it to me,  for the life of me my brain couldn't process any of this.

@DasherLove See What should I do when someone answers my question?.
